# Show AlertDialog on HttpClient exception (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

My Xamarin Android app utilizes a Web service, which it connects to using HttpClient. On no connection (for exmaple when the user has no cell nor WiFi connection), an excpetion is thrown. I'm using async/await to get the data from the server. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
    public async Task<String> doLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        String url = Constants.loginEndpoint + username + "/" + password + "/";
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));

        return_string = "";

        try
        {
            var response = await GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return_string = "success";
                // Process the positive response here
            else
            { }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ConnectionException();
        }

        return return_string;
    }
```

I defined a custon ConnectionException and want to show an AlertDialog to the user to inform them, that the request failed due to no connection. After the user clicks OK I want to close the app. I tried to show the alert dialog in the following way, but it's not working:

```
    public class ConnectionException : Exception
{
    public ConnectionException()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp.Context);
        alert.SetTitle("Failure");
        alert.SetMessage("Request failed. No connection.");
        alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
        });

        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }

    public ConnectionException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }

    public ConnectionException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }
}
```

Is this the right approach? Probably not, as it's not working. I would appreciate any help on how to achieve this. Also, I've not given it too much thought, but is this a preferred way to handle such exceptions?

Comment: the exception object itself shouldn't be responsible for displaying a message.  You are also (possibly) trying to display a UI alert on a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `myApp.Context` is an `Activity` and it has no back stack, you can just call `Finish()`

```
var context = myApp.Context; // this needs to be an Activity-based context...
context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    var alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .SetTitle("Failure")
        .SetMessage("Request failed. No connection.")
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            context.Finish();
        })
        .Create();
    alertDialog.Show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reusing this exception in several places, or is this a one off?
If your only using this exception once, there is no real reason to build your own.
You may as well just capture the exception and post your alert from inside your catch.

I know that's not as pretty of a way to write the catch, but if it works why not use it.

Side note: 
DisplayAlert may be easier for you as well. It'll be a one liner.

Example:

```
await DisplayAlert("Failure","Request failed. No connection.", "Ok");
```

Comment: DisplayAlert is XF, he is just doing Android

Comment: I am aware. I'm unsure if they were already using XF in the application. If they are, just use DisplayAlert, other wise, they would likely ignore that portion.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are handling possible errors contains multiple issues and is not the right approach for several reasons.

First: Your code doesn't follow C-Sharp conventions and contains several code-smells. I show you a better and more accepted style.

1) Methods in C# normally starts with an uppercase letter. `doLogin` becomes `Login`

2) To create a new Uri instance you do not need to format your url-string. The string.Empty won't be used. So the code can be simplified into `await GetAsync(new Uri(...));`

3) The return_string seems not to be used in any way outside the method. It is string.Empty or "success". Why not switch it to bool? That way you can easily check if the login was successful. The return-type becomes bool instead of string.

The method looks now like this:

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
{
    //TODO: Do parameter check for username and password

    try
    {
        var response = await GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.loginEndpoint + username + "/" + password + "/"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Process the positive response here

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ConnectionException();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Second, as mentioned by @Jason, an exception should not contain any UI or business logic. Consider the following, which will break your current implementation.

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
{
   var connectionEx = new ConnectionException();

    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw connectionEx;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now your user will see the exception even so there wasn't any.

The last thing is that I recommend not to catch the exception just to throw your custom exception. The reason is, that there might be other things that raise an exception too. For example something is null in the positive response handling.

Depending on how the Login method is used, for example directly in an Android Activity, I would do something like that:

```
public async Task Login(string username, string password)
{
    //TODO: Do parameter check for username and password

    try
    {
        var response = await GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.loginEndpoint + username + "/" + password + "/"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Process the positive response here
        }
        else
        {
            var alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
               .SetTitle("Failure")
               .SetMessage("Request failed.")
               .SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
                   {
                       Finish();
                   })
               .Create();

            alertDialog.Show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .SetTitle("Failure")
            .SetMessage("Something went wrong (" + ex.Message +")")
            .SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                   Finish();
                })
            .Create();

        alertDialog.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) I do not normally program in C#, that's why I did not follow the mentioned convention, so now it is pointless to change aaaall the methods in my code just for the sake of starting them with an upper case letter. 2) Your suggestion is right, I should not be using string.Empty here. 3) The purpose of string as a return value is to be able to return a specified message to the calling function. I did not design and implement the server API, that is why I wanted the method to be flexible enought to handle "messages". 
Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I tested your code and the AlertDialog is not shown. Instead, there's another exception raised after Show().

Comment: Ok, my bad, it was my other part of the code that threw the exception. I used the solution from @SushiHangover, as yours would not work due to AlertDialog being created on a background thread of async method.